# Getting array values from separate text file

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2012

This is my first attempt at getting a bunch of values from a separate text document. I have a separate text file named P.txt with the following values 13 49
16 2
4 0
90 60
40 20
60 -100
7 1
5 9
3 3
15 -22
11 7
12 3
I have never tried to get data from an outside file to put into an array and while working I keep getting errors on line 15 which is:

```
read_data(int nums[], int size);
```

Visual studio says that it is expecting a ")" after int and that the read_data function does not take 0 arguments. Can anyone explain these errors to me and help guide me in the right direction? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void read_data(int nums[], int size);

int main()
{
    const int size = 24;
    ifstream dataIn;
    double lab[size];

    cout << "The numbers on file are:\n "; 
    read_data(int nums[], int size);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void read_data(int nums[], int size)
{
    ifstream dataIn;
    dataIn.open("P.txt");

    if( dataIn.fail() )
            {
                    cout << "File does not exist." << endl;
                    exit(1);
            } 

    int count;
    for ( count = 0; count < size; count++ )
    {
            dataIn >> nums[count];
}

    dataIn.close(); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the line `read_data(int nums[],int size);`

You cannot declare a variable in a function call.

Also, you cannot use `system("pause")` without `stdlib.h` or `cstdlib`

Use this instead :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void read_data(int nums[], int size);

int main()
{
    const int size = 24;
    ifstream dataIn;
    double lab[size];
    int nums[size];

    cout << "The numbers on file are:\n ";
    read_data(nums, size);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void read_data(int nums[], int size)
{
    ifstream dataIn;
    dataIn.open("P.txt");

    if( dataIn.fail() )
    {
            cout << "File does not exist." << endl;
            exit(1);
    }

    int count;
    for ( count = 0; count < size; count++ )
    {
            dataIn >> nums[count];
}

    dataIn.close(); }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks. I knew I was over thinking it when I couldn't figure out that I needed to int nums[size]. Thanks for your time!!